# koa and sqlite3 node REST endpoint returning only Database object instead of data

Tags: node.js, sqlite, async-await, koa

I have a simple GET route setup with Koa and sql3lite that fetches from a json file some data, with the use of a wrapper.

A helper sql3lite wrapper exposes an initialize function for the main server `index.js` file to load into memory on startup:

**index.js**

```
const data = require('./data');

data.initialize();

const server = createServer();

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

The `data.js` file serves as a wrapper around the [sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) node library, so routes can call the `connection()` method individually.

**data.js**

```
const connection = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

function initialize() {
  connection.serialize(() => {
    connection.run('CREATE TABLE meter_reads (cumulative INTEGER, reading_date STRING, unit STRING)');

    const { electricity } = sampleData;
    electricity.forEach((data) => {
      connection.run(
        'INSERT INTO meter_reads (cumulative, reading_date, unit) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
        [data.cumulative, data.readingDate, data.unit],
      );
    });
  });
}

module.exports = {
  initialize,
  connection,
};
```

The **problem** I am having is sending the data object back to a client or postman when calling the exported `connection` method:

**koa route**

```
const db = require('../data');
router.get('/meter/readings', async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = await db.connection.all('SELECT * FROM meter_reads', (err, data) => data);
});
```

**GET request to route result**: 
`{
    "open": true,
    "filename": ":memory:",
    "mode": 65542
}`

**Interesting quirk:**

By wrapping the `data` object, produced by the `db.connection.all()` method above with `console.log()`, I can print out the expected data on the node server. It's almost like `ctx.body` is screwing up something. I've been an express guy up until now so apologies if this is a rookie mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by GMS here:
https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/1046#issuecomment-425643910

'all' does not return any value ( it returns the result by calling the given callback) so you are actually awaiting 'db.connection' in this line of code
there are some libraries based on node-sqlite3 providing promise based API and more
e.g
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite
or mine:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3orm